# Как сменить стандартный цвет фона Laravel Breeze?

Tags: laravel, bootstrap, auth, blade, background-color

Для аутентификации использовал Laravel Breeze, там по умолчанию серый цвет фона [image: вот такой]

Я не могу найти как изменить цвет и сделать фон темным( прикрепил код шаблонов и страницу для входа

layout.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <title>@yield('title')</title>
        <header class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row align-items-center p-3 px-md-4 mb-3 text-white border-bottom shadow-sm">
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info" href="/">MyTeacher</a>
            <nav class="my-2 my-md-0 me-md-3">
                <a class="p-2 text-white" href="/journal">Електронний журнал</a>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Styles -->
        <style>
            /*! normalize.css v8.0.1 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */html{line-height:1.15;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}body{margin:0}a{background-color:transparent}[hidden]{display:none}html{font-family:system-ui,-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Segoe UI,Roboto,Helvetica Neue,Arial,Noto Sans,sans-serif,Apple Color Emoji,Segoe UI Emoji,Segoe UI Symbol,Noto Color Emoji;line-height:1.5}*,:after,:before{box-sizing:border-box;border:0 solid #e2e8f0}a{color:inherit;text-decoration:inherit}svg,video{display:block;vertical-align:middle}video{max-width:100%;height:auto}.bg-white{--bg-opacity:1;background-color:#fff;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,var(--bg-opacity))}.bg-gray-100{--bg-opacity:1;background-color:#f7fafc;background-color:rgba(247,250,252,var(--bg-opacity))}.border-gray-200{--border-opacity:1;border-color:#edf2f7;border-color:rgba(237,242,247,var(--border-opacity))}.border-t{border-top-width:1px}.flex{display:flex}.grid{display:grid}.hidden{display:none}.items-center{align-items:center}.justify-center{justify-content:center}.font-semibold{font-weight:600}.h-5{height:1.25rem}.h-8{height:2rem}.h-16{height:4rem}.text-sm{font-size:.875rem}.text-lg{font-size:1.125rem}.leading-7{line-height:1.75rem}.mx-auto{margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto}.ml-1{margin-left:.25rem}.mt-2{margin-top:.5rem}.mr-2{margin-right:.5rem}.ml-2{margin-left:.5rem}.mt-4{margin-top:1rem}.ml-4{margin-left:1rem}.mt-8{margin-top:2rem}.ml-12{margin-left:3rem}.-mt-px{margin-top:-1px}.max-w-6xl{max-width:72rem}.min-h-screen{min-height:100vh}.overflow-hidden{overflow:hidden}.p-6{padding:1.5rem}.py-4{padding-top:1rem;padding-bottom:1rem}.px-6{padding-left:1.5rem;padding-right:1.5rem}.pt-8{padding-top:2rem}.fixed{position:fixed}.relative{position:relative}.top-0{top:0}.right-0{right:0}.shadow{box-shadow:0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1),0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.06)}.text-center{text-align:center}.text-gray-200{--text-opacity:1;color:#edf2f7;color:rgba(237,242,247,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-300{--text-opacity:1;color:#e2e8f0;color:rgba(226,232,240,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-400{--text-opacity:1;color:#cbd5e0;color:rgba(203,213,224,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-500{--text-opacity:1;color:#a0aec0;color:rgba(160,174,192,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-600{--text-opacity:1;color:#718096;color:rgba(113,128,150,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-700{--text-opacity:1;color:#4a5568;color:rgba(74,85,104,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-900{--text-opacity:1;color:#1a202c;color:rgba(26,32,44,var(--text-opacity))}.underline{text-decoration:underline}.antialiased{-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale}.w-5{width:1.25rem}.w-8{width:2rem}.w-auto{width:auto}.grid-cols-1{grid-template-columns:repeat(1,minmax(0,1fr))}@media (min-width:640px){.sm\:rounded-lg{border-radius:.5rem}.sm\:block{display:block}.sm\:items-center{align-items:center}.sm\:justify-start{justify-content:flex-start}.sm\:justify-between{justify-content:space-between}.sm\:h-20{height:5rem}.sm\:ml-0{margin-left:0}.sm\:px-6{padding-left:1.5rem;padding-right:1.5rem}.sm\:pt-0{padding-top:0}.sm\:text-left{text-align:left}.sm\:text-right{text-align:right}}@media (min-width:768px){.md\:border-t-0{border-top-width:0}.md\:border-l{border-left-width:1px}.md\:grid-cols-2{grid-template-columns:repeat(2,minmax(0,1fr))}}@media (min-width:1024px){.lg\:px-8{padding-left:2rem;padding-right:2rem}}@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark){.dark\:bg-gray-800{--bg-opacity:1;background-color:#2d3748;background-color:rgba(45,55,72,var(--bg-opacity))}.dark\:bg-gray-900{--bg-opacity:1;background-color:#1a202c;background-color:rgba(26,32,44,var(--bg-opacity))}.dark\:border-gray-700{--border-opacity:1;border-color:#4a5568;border-color:rgba(74,85,104,var(--border-opacity))}.dark\:text-white{--text-opacity:1;color:#fff;color:rgba(255,255,255,var(--text-opacity))}.dark\:text-gray-400{--text-opacity:1;color:#cbd5e0;color:rgba(203,213,224,var(--text-opacity))}}
        </style>

        <style>
            body {
                font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
            }
            .mx-auto {
    margin-right: auto!important;
    margin-left: auto!important;
}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body class="antialiased bg-dark">
        <div class=align-items-center relative flex items-top justify-center min-h-screen bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-900 sm:items-center py-4 sm:pt-0">
            @if (Route::has('login'))
                <div class="hidden fixed top-0 right-0 px-6 py-4 sm:block">
                    @auth
                        <a href="{{ url('/dashboard') }}" class="text-sm text-gray-700 underline">Dashboard</a>
                    @else
                        <a href="{{ route('login') }}" class="text-sm text-gray-700 underline">Log in</a>

                        @if (Route::has('register'))
                            <a href="{{ route('register') }}" class="ml-4 text-sm text-gray-700 underline">Register</a>
                        @endif
                    @endauth
                </div>
            @endif
            <div class="container">
                @yield('content')
            </div>
                </body>
            </html>
```

app.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap">

        <!-- Styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">

        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body class="font-sans antialiased">
        <div class="min-h-screen bg-gray-100">
            @include('layouts.navigation')

            <!-- Page Heading -->
            <header class="bg-dark shadow">
                <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-6 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                    {{ $header }}
                </div>
            </header>

            <!-- Page Content -->
            <main>
                {{ $slot }}
            </main>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

guest.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap">

        <!-- Styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">

        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="bg-dark font-sans text-gray-900 antialiased">
            {{ $slot }}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

login.blade.php

```
<x-guest-layout>
    <x-auth-card>
        <x-slot name="logo">
            <a href="/">
                <x-application-logo class="w-20 h-20 fill-current text-red-500" />
            </a>
        </x-slot>

        <!-- Session Status -->
        <x-auth-session-status class="mb-4" :status="session('status')" />

        <!-- Validation Errors -->
        <x-auth-validation-errors class="mb-4" :errors="$errors" />

        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
            @csrf

            <!-- Email Address -->
            <div>
                <x-label for="email" :value="__('Email')" />

                <x-input id="email" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="email" name="email" :value="old('email')" required autofocus />
            </div>

            <!-- Password -->
            <div class="mt-4">
                <x-label for="password" :value="__('Password')" />

                <x-input id="password" class="block mt-1 w-full"
                                type="password"
                                name="password"
                                required autocomplete="current-password" />
            </div>

            <!-- Remember Me -->
            <div class="block mt-4">
                <label for="remember_me" class="inline-flex items-center">
                    <input id="remember_me" type="checkbox" class="rounded border-gray-300 text-indigo-600 shadow-sm focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50" name="remember">
                    <span class="ml-2 text-sm text-gray-600">{{ __('Remember me') }}</span>
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="flex items-center justify-end mt-4">
                @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                    <a class="underline text-sm text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                        {{ __('Forgot your password?') }}
                    </a>
                @endif

                <x-button class="ml-3">
                    {{ __('Log in') }}
                </x-button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </x-auth-card>
</x-guest-layout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой способ был бы для Вас, это посмотреть через инспектор, но могу предположить что в файле `app.blade.php` нужно заменить класс `bg-gray-100`

```
<body class="font-sans antialiased">
    <div class="min-h-screen bg-gray-100">
        ...
    </div>
</body>
```

так как там по-умолчанию вроде как tailwind, то список классов которые можете применить из коробки можно посмотреть [здесь](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-color)

Comment: Спасибо большое, я пробывал что-то там менять но писал bg-dark как в bootstrap) и по этому ничего не происходило, ещё раз спасибо